# Regular expression to validate National Identity Card number which has 9 digits with final digit being X or V

Tags: javascript, devexpress

```js
function PassportValidate(s, e) {
  var option = rbIdentityVerification.GetValue().toString(); //gets the selected option which is NIC selected by default. devexpress radiobuttonlist
  var text = e.value.toString(); //gets the value from the textbox

  if (option == "NIC") {
    var pattern2 = RegExp("^\d{9}(X|V)$");

    if (!pattern2.test(text)) {
      e.isValid = false;
      e.errorText = "Passport number invalid.(Max 9 numbers)"; //Error message that is to be shown
    }
  }
}
```

Regular expression to validate National Identity Card number which has 9 digits with final digit being X or V. the code always return invalid, so even a correct **NIC** is entered still returns as invalid

Comment: please ignore the error text...

Answer (score 2):

Though `\d` is modern regex shorthand for `[0-9]`, I prefer to use latter.

This regex work fine `^([0-9]{9})(X|V)$`.

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqwy51g/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using This (Sri Lanka NIC new and old formats). This will accept all the numbers with V or X (Upper or lower).

```
/^([0-9]{9})(X|V)$|^([0-9]{11})/gis
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may will help you

```
^\d{9}[V|v|X|x]$
```